# Slave datanode not working in hadoop 0.20.2 and slave not able communicating with master@54310

Tags: macos, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

Could you please elaborate on your answer. I am stuck with similar issues. My hadoop process is running fine. I am using my macbook laptop local machine as master and aws ec2 instance as "slave". Although the datanode is active in slave its not live to run my process.

below is my /etc/hosts from both nodes

in my pc master node
    `##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    #::1             localhost
    xxx      master
    abc   slave1
    abc   slave2`

in slave ec2 instance
    127.0.0.1 localhost

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
xxx master
abc slave1
abc slave2
```

slave log file entry:

```
2016-03-18 11:04:05,826 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode:     STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = 
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.2
STARTUP_MSG:   build =         https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20 -r 911707;     compiled by 'chrisdo' on Fri Feb 19 08:07:34 UTC 2010
************************************************************/
2016-03-18 11:04:27,273 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to     server: master/xxx:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).
2016-03-18 11:04:48,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/xxx:54310. Already tried 1 time(s).
```

Please help me with this I am stuck for two days. I also looked in to this post [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=435915#435915) from the aws forum and many other links but dint help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not run the master node on your own laptop, but with data nodes running on ec2. This is because those ec2 servers cannot reach your laptop via ip "10.0.0.130", which is always provided by your ISP:

```
ping 10.0.0.130
PING 10.0.0.130 (10.0.0.130): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
```

You can log into your ec2 machine and ping the IP, it will not work. Move your master node to ec2 and make sure every machine in your cluster as well as every role in your hadoop deployment has the right access to each other.

Comment: so you mean there is no other way this could be achieved between a local machine and aws ec2 instance?

Comment: And by the way, it's not good practice to post your IPs of ec2 machines on the internet, otherwise black hat hackers may attack them.

Comment: If your local machine has a static IP which ec2 machine can reach, your deployment would be okay. **And only okay under a testing, never under a production.**

Comment: ya I know about that this instance is just for testing purpose I am going to shut it down it soon

Comment: So just have fun with hadoop. :P

Comment: I tried with both master and slave as ec2 instances the issue still remains same. slave not able to connect to master

Comment: Do you set up firewalls on your machine?

Comment: Actually I figured it out we need to allow all TCP and all ICMP in inbound rules of your web server. Thanks for your help.